# UMP test for poisson vs geometric

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, geometric-distribution

I have two hypotheses:

$H_0\!: X\sim\rm{Pos}(1)$
 $H_1\!: \rm{Geometric}(0.5)$ for any $\alpha$ in $(0,1)$

How can I construct a uniformly most powerful (UMP) test?

I used the ratio under the $H_0$ and $H_1$ bigger than some $k$, and then got:

> $x!(0.5)^{x}>k/(0.5e)=c$

But I cannot recognize what the distribution of 
$x!(0.5)^{x}$ if $X$ follow $\rm{Pos}(1)$

Comment: Are you sure you have that right? Please show your work. I assume we're looking at a single observation?

Comment: yes, it is a single observation